# Disabling bean construction with a ThrowIllegalArgumentException

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

How can I disable (under certain circumstances) direct access to a group pages controlled by a single bean without using serlvets or filters?  Right now I have something like this :

```
   public SomeBeanController() {
    try {
      FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("/somewhere.xhtml");
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Direct access is disabled...");
   }

   public SomeBeanController(Integer someId) {
     this.someId = someId;
   }
```

The default bean constructor does a redirect to a more appropriate page.  The other constructor is called from another bean only when we need access to the group of pages.

Thank's!

Comment: An idea would be using a parameter which says if the managed bean should redirect or not to the *somewhere.xhtml* view. Still, I don't understand why you don't want to use a Servlet Filter, is like using a piece of flannel to clean your laptop, in other words, using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: Thank's for your answer.  I followed your advice and I'm now using a filter.